# Is there a less verbose way to find a object key in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sadly I cannot change the data that I receive. So I found a way around it but I feel like it's a bit messy.

Here is an example of the data that I am working with:

```
var x = {
    // a simple array, we like these.
    data1: ['this', 'that', 'other'],
    
    // I don't know why it's like this, and I can't change it
    data2: [ {name:'joe'}, {name:'john'} ]
}
```

the goal is to run a bit of code if `data1` or `data2` have the name: joe.

```
if( x.data1.includes('joe') || x.data2.includes('joe') ){...}
```

Obviously, the second condition would not work with the data.

I turned to format `data2` into a simple array with a function:

```
var formatData2 = function(){
    var arr = [];
    for( i in x.data2 ){
        arr.push( x.data2[i].name );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This then lets me use this logic:

```
if( x.data1.includes('joe') || formatData2().includes('joe') ){...}
```

The question is:

Can I avoid formatting `data2` into an array to check the values in an if statement?

```js
var x = {
    data1: ['this', 'that', 'other'],
    data2: [ {name:'joe'}, {name:'john'} ]
}

var formatData2 = function(){
    var arr = [];
    for( i in x.data2 ){
        arr.push( x.data2[i].name );
    }
    return arr;
}

if( x.data1.includes('joe') || formatData2().includes('joe') ){
    console.log( true );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```
if (x.data1.includes('joe') || x.data2.some(el => el.name == 'joe'))
```

BTW, your `formatData2()` function can be simplified using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function formatData2(x) {
    return x.data2.map(el => el.name);
}
```

Comment: Now I feel silly, I swear I've used .some() in the past.
and thanks for the extra bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to loop over the array of objects and will return true when the condition is met.

```js
var x = {
    data1: ['this', 'that', 'other'],
    data2: [ {name:'joe'}, {name:'john'}, ],
};

const result = x.data1.includes('joe') || x.data2.some(({name})=> name === 'joe');
console.log(result);
```